# NLog for asp.net core is not filtering Microsoft logs

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following `nlog.config` file in ASP.NET Core 2.1 project. However, it's logging messages from every logger (including Microsoft logger) to console.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="${specialfolder:folder=UserProfile}\nlog\internal-nlog.txt">

  <variable name="fullLayout" value="${shortdate}  [${uppercase:${level}}]  ${logger}: ${message}  ${exception:format=tostring}  url: ${aspnet-request-url}" />

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write to console -->
    <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${fullLayout}" />

    <!-- write to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="allfile"
            fileName="${defaultDirectory}/test-api-all.log"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveFileName="${defaultDirectory}/test-api-all-${#}.log"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            maxArchiveFiles="5"
            layout="${fullLayout}" />

    <!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="ownFile-web"
            fileName="${defaultDirectory}/test-api-app.log"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveFileName="${defaultDirectory}/test-api-app-${#}.log"
            archiveNumbering="Date"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            maxArchiveFiles="5"
            layout="${fullLayout}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />

    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I do not have any logging settings in `appsettings.json` files. All logger configuration in in `nlog.config`. In the `Program.cs`, I'm registering NLog like:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.ClearProviders())
                .UseNLog()
                .Build();
```

How can I filter out Microsoft logs?

EDIT:

Above configuration started working without a problem the next day without me making any changes :O

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this will work:

```
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
  </rules>
```

The order of the logging rules are important, as the rules are matched from the top. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Comment: Somehow, my original config started working without a problem the next day... Upvoted your answer, thanks for taking time to help me :)

Comment: I've never quite understood the one for "Microsoft.*".. the comment says it is used to skip non-critical Microsoft logs, yet the xml look like it's doing the reverse? Surely setting maxLevel="Info" means you will get all the unwanted guff, and none of the warning/error/critical logging?

Comment: @Murphybro2 The logging rules are evaluated from top and down. But logging-rules marked with `final="true"` will prevent LogEvents for reaching other rules further down. So the first rule will match any Logger where name starts with "Microsoft" and where LogLevel is Info (or less severe). Because of `final="true"` it will prevent that output from reaching other rules, and the output will just be discarded since the first rule has no `writeTo`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Answer (score 1):

The order of your logging rules seems to be correct. I suggest trying to double check if your updated `nlog.config` file is being copied to the build directory (e.g. `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\nlog.config`)

I kind of encountered the same issue, but found out that debugging using Visual Studio, it sometimes doesn't really copy the `nlog.config` file to your build directory. So the solution is to Clean the project first, then Build, and finally Debug.

Comment: Yes, I saw this happened too. But on this particular occasion, I had tried cleaning (even manually deleting the files in the bin folder). My guess is some caching was messing with it.